# Tensorflow for poets

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow for poets there is a script called `label_image.py` that takes a single image and spits out 5 predictions based on probabilities. Is there a way to give it an entire folder of images and ask it store the predictions one by one maybe in a text file or so?

the link to the file -https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#5

Comment: Add a link to that script to greatly increase the number of people capable of answering your question.

Comment: Probably you can't just alter that script, or else some other code will not work. Instead, just write _another_ function, using e.g. `os.listdir` to get all the image files in a folder, apply the function from that script to each file, and return the result, e.g. as a dictionary mapping file names to predictions.

Comment: thanks.ill try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and worked pretty well for me. Below is the code that you may want to try. You can make changes if you need something very specific.

```
import os, sys
import glob
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# change this as you see fit
image_path = sys.argv[1]

extension = ['*.jpeg', '*.jpg']
files=[]

for e in extension:
directory = os.path.join(image_path, e)
fileList = glob.glob(directory)
for f in fileList:
    files.append(f)

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
           in tf.gfile.GFile("/path_to_file/retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/path_to_file/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    # Read in the image_data
    for file in files:
        image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(file, 'rb').read()

        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                       {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
        top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]
        print("Image Name: " + file)
        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply

Comment: Shrikanth  ,i cant- i have less than 15 rep points- but in case i do manage to surpass it ,ill come back and accpet it!